# How wcf catch exception before exe user code

Tags: wcf, exception, handle

How WCF catch exception before exe user code?
There are a lot of topic about how to solve the misconfig in the config file, like:
[The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ad1bf1c-e340-44ae-8ba5-91428d6e78a7/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192-has-been-exceeded-while-reading-xml-data). If developer doesn't config the configuration correctly, the client will get a error.

I send a very large request to WCF service, before the WCF engine exe my code, WCF engine has returned a message to client. I think this is not an unhandle exception, because on server side, there is no exception throw.

Now I want to catch this kind of exception before wcf return the result to client.
I set a breakpoint at the first line of my code, but it didn't hit the breakpoint, and the client got the error message. Before exe the user code, wcf engine return a error message to client.

I don't wish to hide the .net Exception, but I hope to do something before the WCF engine return.
It seems like WCF return a HTTP code of 500 (not 200).

Comment: If you're talking about catching any unhandled errors in your service code, you can look at implementing `IErrorHandler`.  If you're talking about catching the specific error above before it reaches the client, you can't - that is happening when the *client* is trying to read the message.  Take a look at [WCF Extensibility - IErrorHandler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/07/wcf-extensibility-ierrorhandler.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I mean that I want to cath some kind of specific errors like i mentioned in that link, which is an example of such error.

Comment: You can easily catch errors within your service via try-catch blocks or implementing IErrorHandler in the case of otherwise uncaught exceptions.  Anything outside of that will be more difficult and may be impossible depending on where the error occurs.  I believe the error above would happen before your service code is ever executed, so I don't know how you would catch it.  You might look at implmenting `IDispatchMessageInspector` and examining the length of the request in `AfterReceiveRequest`, but I'm not 100% sure that the message will get that far before it errors out.